# window form c# to sort room list which is a string

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, xmpp

I took over a project from one of our developers.

We have a window form we use to send in a string for which openfire chat rooms a user has access to.

Some rooms are named "AAA ROOM 1" and "AAA ROOM 2" etc.
If I am using this code it sorts it by "AAA ROOM 1" "AAA ROOM 11" then after "AAA ROOM 19" comes "AAA ROOM 2"

```
RoomList.BeginUpdate();

foreach (Room r in Rooms) // original room list before getting it sorted
{
    RoomList.Items.Add(r.Name, IsMember(r.ID));
}

RoomList.EndUpdate();
```

So I wanted to sort it in the right order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) so I added some code to sort the rooms list and its sorting it correctly,

```
foreach (Room r in Rooms)
{
    if (r.Name.Contains("AAA") && r.Name.Length <= 7)
                RoomList.Items.Add(r.Name, IsMember(r.ID));
}
foreach (Room r in Rooms)
{
    if (r.Name.Contains("AAA") && r.Name.Length > 7)
        RoomList.Items.Add(r.Name, IsMember(r.ID));
}
foreach (Room r in Rooms)
{
    if (!r.Name.Contains("AAA"))
        RoomList.Items.Add(r.Name, IsMember(r.ID));
}
```

But when I save the data it uses this code here, but it's not marking the right room.
This is the code it uses to save the memberships (if I check off to add "AAA Room 11" then it actually saves it as "AAA Room 18").

```
MasterRecord.User.Memberships = "";
foreach (object o in RoomList.CheckedIndices)
{
    if (MasterRecord.User.Memberships.Length > 0)
        MasterRecord.User.Memberships += ",";

    MasterRecord.User.Memberships += GetItem(roomsui.StrToInt(o.ToString())).ToString();
}
```

Please understand I am kind of new to this developing, so I'll need some help with how to sort it correctly when retrieving it and when saving it.

Also, I want to be able to have a pop up window if a user puts a check into certain rooms.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to make a custom comparer; if rooms follow a specific format, your custom comparer, for example, could split after a known point and then sort by the room index. So if you have AAA Room 1, AAA Room 2, AA Room 1, then if you split after 'room' and then sort by components, that will probably do what you need.

Comment: have you seen my answere? you can use a custom alpha numeric comparer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, looking at this as a matter of length determining which room is sorted first is wrongheaded. If the pattern for the name of a room is `{ROOM-NAME}_{ROOM_NUMBER}`, then treat it as such. (As much as I hate to say this, sometimes: *this might be a job for Regular Expressions!*)

```
var unordered = new[] { "CCC ROOM 10", "CCC ROOM 5", "AAA ROOM 1", "AAA ROOM 14", "AAA ROOM 2", "AAA ROOM 10", "AAA ROOM 5", "BBB ROOM 3", "BBB ROOM 12" };

Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(\D+)(\d+)$");

var ordered = unordered
    .Select(
        r =>
        {
            Match match = pattern.Match(r);
            return new
            {
                Name = r,
                Prefix = match.Groups[1].Value,
                Number = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value)
            };
        }
    )
    .OrderBy(r => r.Prefix)
    .ThenBy(r => r.Number);

foreach (var room in ordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(room.Name);
}
```

This code produces the following output...

```
AAA ROOM 1
AAA ROOM 2
AAA ROOM 5
AAA ROOM 10
AAA ROOM 14
BBB ROOM 3
BBB ROOM 12
CCC ROOM 5
CCC ROOM 10
```

With this method, we're calling a rose a rose (or, specifically, a string-representation-of-a-number a number). I used the anonymous type so that I didn't have to run the match twice.

**EDIT**: I noticed you said Visual Studio 2008, so you might not be using .NET 4.0. If you aren't, that multi-line lambda might not work (I don't remember exactly when that was added.). Here's another way using two regexes and no anonymous type. I'm not sure I don't just like this way better anyway, now that I've written it...

```
var rooms = new[] { "CCC ROOM 10", "CCC ROOM 5", "AAA ROOM 1", "AAA ROOM 14", "AAA ROOM 2", "AAA ROOM 10", "AAA ROOM 5", "BBB ROOM 3", "BBB ROOM 12" };

Regex prefix = new Regex(@"^\D+");
Regex suffix = new Regex(@"\d+$");

var ordered2 = rooms
    .OrderBy(r => prefix.Match(r).Value)
    .ThenBy(r => Convert.ToInt32(suffix.Match(r).Value));

foreach (var room in ordered2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(room);
}
```

Also, I might note that there is obviously no contingency in this code for a failure to match the name. If that's a possibility, that would need to be built in.

And finally, since you said you were new to development, I'll touch on the regular expressions real quick:

`^\D+` = From the start of the string, find me something that isn't a digit one or more times.

`\d+$` = Find me a set of one or more digits that are immediately followed by the end of the string.

**EDIT2**: I suppose I didn't answer your second question. The answer to that could vary quite a bit based on how the form is initialized from the room list, how you're storing the checkboxes, how you want to handle it, what other data structures exist to hold the rest of the information and so on.

Comment: i am trying to use it, now i am getting an error saying "The name 'OrderBy' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: (1) What version of .NET are you on?
(2) Assuming it supports LINQ, you'll need a `using System.Linq;` at the top. I don't remember whether the LINQ stuff exists in `System` or `System.Core` or somewhere else, so you might also have to add a reference.

Comment: i was on 2. of .net (thats how the project was handed over to me) and i noticed if i move to 3.5 then i dont get that error (boy, i have some learning to do), any wasy way to do this?

Comment: is there any easy to make a list into string? because the Web Service has the info in a string, lets say if you have access to room1 its actually just a 1, if you have access to room 28 then its number 28,. the XML field looks like this <Memberships>1,7,8,24</Memberships> can i make my own list ?

Comment: i should also mention, the code currently letting me know which room the member is a member in currently is    private bool IsMember(int i)
        {
            string[] parts;
            char[] seps = { ',' };

            parts = MasterRecord.User.Memberships.Split(seps);
            for (int x = 0; x < parts.Length; x++)
                if (i == roomsui.StrToInt(parts[x]))
                    return true;
            return false;
        }

Comment: I feel like this question is becoming a lot bigger in requiring knowledge of your system and how the stuff flows all the way through. I'm not saying it's too big for a question here, but you might want to write a new question with more information and more of a total information lifecycle laid out in sequence detailing how you get it, what format it's in, what you want to do with it and what you want the final result to be. (More or less, I don't want to answer new questions in the comments on the answer for this one, you know?)

Comment: its not really becoming bigger,. i posted the code used for the application to do it, but the only issue is sorting it, and i dont know where to post the code your sending me, like i explained i am new to this and i need almost hands on guidance

Answer (score 0):

First, lets refactor your code a little, beccause it is quite hard to read it:

```
private int RoomWeight(Room r) {
    if (r.Name.Contains("AAA")) {
        if (r.Name.Length > 7) return 2;
        return 1;
    }
    return 3;
}
```

then, you can use to sort your rooms just one line: `var sortedRooms = Rooms.OrderBy(x => RoomWeight(x)).ToList();`

The next step will be to parse a room name and calculate RoomWeight value according to your new requirements

Finally, you'll need to use your sorted list of rooms to fill RoomList.Items list, you can do this the same way it was done:

```
 foreach (var r in sortedRooms) {
      RoomList.Items.Add(r.Name, IsMember(r.ID));
 }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: It is just a private method - place it somewhere inside of your class

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a alphanumeric sort (can be used for other sorts with numerics too).

try this fast solution for it:

C# Alphanumeric Sorting
http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string[] highways = new string[]
    {
        "100F",
        "50F",
        "SR100",
        "SR9"
    };
    //
    // We want to sort a string[] array called highways in an
    // alphanumeric way. Call the static Array.Sort method.
    //
    Array.Sort(highways, new AlphanumComparatorFast());
    //
    // Display the results
    //
    foreach (string h in highways)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(h);
    }
    }
}
```

usage of your problem

```
var unordered = new[] { "CCC ROOM 10", "CCC ROOM 5", "AAA ROOM 1", "AAA ROOM 14", "AAA ROOM 2", "AAA ROOM 10", "AAA ROOM 5", "BBB ROOM 3", "BBB ROOM 12" };
var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(s => s, new AlphanumComparatorFast());
```

here is the result

```
AAA ROOM 1
AAA ROOM 2
AAA ROOM 5
AAA ROOM 10
AAA ROOM 14
BBB ROOM 3
BBB ROOM 12
CCC ROOM 5
CCC ROOM 10
```

here is a nice article about the problem:

Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html

Comment: Liked my test list eh? **:)**.